# Angular 8: ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined

Tags: angular, api, geolocation, observable, angular8

I'm getting ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined every time when I'm trying to log my api result in the browser.
Here is my service class

```js
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';

    @Injectable({
      providedIn: 'root'
    })
    export class GetlocationService {
      lat:any='';
      long:any='';
      url:any='';
      weatherUrl:any='';


      constructor(private http:HttpClient) {

        if(navigator.geolocation)
        {

          navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition( position=>
          {

            this.lat = position.coords.latitude;
            this.long = position.coords.longitude;
            this.url =`https://us1.locationiq.com/v1/reverse.php?key=[mykey]&lat=${this.lat}&lon=${this.long}&format=json`;

            this.weatherUrl=`https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://api.darksky.net/forecast/[mykey]/${this.lat},${this.long}`;

          })
        }
      }

     public getLocationName()
      {

        return this.http.get(this.url);
      }

      public getWeather()
      {
        return this.http.get(this.weatherUrl);

      }

    }
```

and here is my `locationweather` component from where I'm calling my service.

```js
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { GetlocationService } from '../getlocation.service';
    import { getLocaleDateFormat } from '@angular/common';

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-locationweather',
      templateUrl: './locationweather.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./locationweather.component.css']
    })
    export class LocationweatherComponent implements OnInit {

      constructor( private getLocation:GetlocationService) { }


      locations:any=[];
      weathers:any=[];
      getLocationDetail()
        {
          this.getLocation.getLocationName().subscribe((data:any)=> 
          {
           console.log(data)
           this.locations.push(data);
          })
        }

        getWeatherDetails()
        {

          this.getLocation.getWeather().subscribe((weather:any)=>
            {

              console.log(weather)
              this.weathers.push(weather)

            })
        }

        focusClear(add)
        {
          add.value="";

        }

        ngOnInit() {
          // this.getLocationDetail();
          this.getWeatherDetails()

        }
    }
```

Can anyone please help me? I'm calling service in `ngOnit` because I need them whenever my page loads.

PS. I just started learning angular and trying to put my knowledge I gained so far in this mini project.

EDIT:After assigning empty string to long, lat, url and weatherUrl, I no more see the `Angular 8: ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined`in the console. Now I'm getting `ERROR HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 200, statusText: "OK", url: "http://localhost:4200/", ok: false, …}` in the console.

Comment: where do you use 'toLowerCase'?

Comment: Try to put initial value for ```lat:any;
  long:any;
  url:any;
  weatherUrl:any;```, It seems that the urls are undefined when using them.

Comment: Are you sure `weatherUrl` is correct? Did you double check the endpoint it gives?

Comment: I was seeing the error in browser console. Now after assigning empty string to lat, long, url and weatherUrl. I'm seeing this error in the console.

 core.js:7187 ERROR HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 200, statusText: "OK", url: "http://localhost:4200/", ok: false, …}

Comment: and yes my ends points are correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please check the values of the attributes this.lat and this.long before  calling weather and location urls? by printing them in the console.

```
   public getLocationName() {
    console.log(this.lat);
    console.log(this.long);
    return this.http.get(this.url);
  }

  public getWeather() {
    return this.http.get(this.weatherUrl);

  }
```

Seems that you need also an access key to access the apis weather and location as mentionned in the urls [myKey]

Try also to test weather and location urls by testing them directlty on the navigator with real values for (lat, long and key) to make sure that they are correct.

**Edit:**

Can you check if you are getting an error while calling `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` method by catching the error as mentionned in the code below:

```
if (navigator.geolocation) {

  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position => {
    console.log('here');
    this.lat = position.coords.latitude;
    this.long = position.coords.longitude;

  },
    error => {
      console.log('-----------------ERROR:--------------');
      console.log(error);
    }
  );

}
```

**Second Edit:**

Got it, `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` needs to be finished before calling both methods getLocationName & getWeather that those 2 methods depends on the output of the previous method. So what you need to to do is to wait for asynchronous methods to finish using basic promises with `async/await`.
Here is a working example:

> **GetLocation Service**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class GetlocationService {
  private lat: any = '';
  private long: any = '';
  url: any = '';
  weatherUrl: any = '';


  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }


  public async initialize() {
    await this.getPosition().then(pos => {
      this.lat = pos.lat;
      this.long = pos.lng;
      console.log(`Positon: ${pos.lng} ${pos.lat}`);
    });
  }

  public getPosition(): Promise<any> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(resp => {
        resolve({ lng: resp.coords.longitude, lat: resp.coords.latitude });
      },
        err => {
          reject(err);
        });
    });

  }

  public getLocationName() {
    console.log('location method :' + this.lat);
    console.log('location method:' + this.long);
    this.url = ''; //update url
    return this.http.get(this.url);

  }

  public getWeather() {
    console.log('weather method:' + this.lat);
    console.log('weather method:' + this.long);
    this.weatherUrl = ''; //update weather url
    return this.http.get(this.weatherUrl);
  }
}
```

> **Component TS**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { GetlocationService } from './location.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private getLocation: GetlocationService) { }


  locations: any = [];
  weathers: any = [];
  getLocationDetail() {
    this.getLocation.getLocationName().subscribe((data: any) => {
      console.log(data)
      this.locations.push(data);
    })
  }

  getWeatherDetails() {
    this.getLocation.getWeather().subscribe((weather: any) => {
      console.log(weather)
      this.weathers.push(weather)

    })
  }

  focusClear(add) {
    add.value = "";

  }

  async ngOnInit() {
    await this.getLocation.initialize();
    this.getLocationDetail();
    this.getWeatherDetails()

  }
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I did what you asked, I console logged all variables and none of them were displayed. Browser console is showing blank output with just line number and file name. Seems like my getLocationName and getWeather method are not able to read my variabled which are defined in the constructor.

Can you please correct way to declare them so that I can read their values in my defined methods. Also hard coded api url is working fine.

Comment: Could you check if you are getting an error while calling getCurrentPosition method ? i updated my answer with the code to add to catch the error.

Comment: I didn't get any error. I'm able to console log my variable values from `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition`. Just that they are accessible in getLocationName and getWeather methods.

Comment: @rahulsinghal i updated my answer, please check Second Edit section and let me know if it works for you.